# How do I pass parameters to a specific function in a server-side php file (from JS) and then return the result to the JS calling function

Tags: javascript, php, html, http, xmlhttprequest

Basically what I'm doing is creating a graphing calculator (using BokehJS), this calculator currently takes some inputs through html, then javascript reads and does calculations with the data, then outputs the resulting graph.

The problem is that we don't want the user to be able to see all the calculations code.
It is fine if they can see getter and setter methods.

What I need it to do is:

1. Get user inputs on HTML page
2. Read inputs with javascript (client-side)
3. Pass the read input data to PHP (on wordpress server) to do the calculations
4. PHP sends the resulting data back to JS
5. JS (client-side) handles what to do and how to display the data from there

We are using a wordpress server, currently I'm just testing on my local computer, so a way that allows testing and deployment would be great.

Currently this is what I have:

myjavascript.js

```js
function test_test(){

    const staticPNVals = getStaticPN(); //send this to php file as parameter to function
    const ret_array = [];
    
    //The below needs to be changed, idk how to do it
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        const myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        ret_array = myObj;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php");
    xmlhttp.send();

    console.log("ret_array is " + ret_array);
}
```

test.php

```php
<?php
function doStuff($myarr) {
    $myarr2 = array();
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        array_push($myarr2, $myarr[$x]);
      }
    return $myarr2;
}

function doOtherStuff(){
    echo "Hello World";
}
?>
```

I would like to have it so that I can have multiple functions in one file, most solutions I saw only had 1 function in each file.

mypage.html

```html
<!-- Just a simple button to call the main Javascript function-->
<input type="button" value="Test function" onclick="test_test()">
```

So basically, the overall question is what do I change the javascript request to, to make it be able to pass parameters to server side PHP and then return to the calling js function

Edit: Even better if theres a way to use server side javascript instead of PHP, as the script is already written in JS and I dont want to rewrite in PHP unless necessary.

Answer (score 0):

How I've solved a similar problem
Js

```
let formData = new formData();
    formData.append("nameOfFunction","function you want to call");
    formData.append("variableA","some value");
fetch("phpFileName.php"{body: formData,method: POST})
    .then((response)=>response.text)
    .then((data)=>{
        //do whatever
    })
```

Php

```
$nameOfFunction = $_POST["nameOfFunction"];  // unsure past this point
echo "<script>".
    $nameOfFunction."();
    function someFunction(){
    }
    <\script>";
```